# Simple way of listing all directories up to git directories

Tags: bash

I have my projects in `${HOME}/projects/` in a hierarchical structure, something like this:

```
${HOME}/projects/
 - custumer1/
   - c1_git_repo1
     - subdir1
     - ...
   - c1_git_repo2
     - ...
 - customer2/
   - c2_project1/
     - c2_p1_git_repo1
       - ...
     - c2_p1_git_repo2
       - ...
 ...
```

I want to fill my CDPATH with all directories below `{$HOME}/projects` up to the git repos. So in the example above this would be:

```
CDPATH=${HOME}/projects/customer1:${HOME}/projects/customer1/c1_git_repo1:${HOME}/projects/customer1/c1_git_repo2:${HOME}/projects/customer2:${HOME}/projects/customer2/c2_project1:${HOME}/projects/customer2/c2_project1/c2_p1_git_repo1:${HOME}/projects/customer2/c2_project1/c2_p1_git_repo2
```

So I need to find all directories below `{$HOME}/projects/`, but stop at any directory which contains a ".git" folder.

Is there some cmd tool that can list the directories for me?

Comment: Try `find "${HOME}" -not -ipath '*/.git*'`.

Comment: mmg, that does not seem to work. I think it just does not list the files in the ".git" directory, but I also want to remove anything next to the .git directory.

Comment: What do you mean by next? So if you have `folder/with/.git` you also don't want `folder/with` to be added? Or just `folder/with/other_folder`?

Comment: With "next" i mean, that i want to skip all directories which are in the same folder as the .git directory. So i want to include folder/with, but Not folder/width/other_folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fetches all directories from `$HOME/projects`, except `.git` and contents of the `.git` directories.

```
paths=$(
find "$HOME/projects/" -mindepth 2 -type d -not -ipath '*/.git*' \
  | while read d
do
  builtin printf %q: "$d"
done
)
echo $paths
```

*Sample output*

```
/home/user/projects/dir\ with\ spaces:/home/user/projects/prj2
```

In the `while` loop we escape directory paths and append a colon by means of bulit-int `printf` function.

The result is stored in `paths` variable.

Comment: But I do not want only the fit repositories, I want all directories below ```{HOME}/projects/```, but not below any git directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this to find the directories:

```
find "$HOME/projects" -type d -execdir test -d {}/.git \; -print -prune
```

This stops the find whenever there's a `.git`, so it won't descend into the repos looking for submodules, nor will it actually descend into any of the `.git` directories themselves.

Next you want to get the result of that command in an array (I named the array `repos`). If you're using bash version 4+, the easiest way to do that is `mapfile`, which won't split on any spaces inside the pathnames:

```
mapfile -t repos < <(
 find "$HOME/projects" -type d -execdir test -d {}/.git \; -print -prune)
```

If you're on a Mac using /bin/bash, you don't have that option, so you can use `read` with an altered `IFS` and the `-d` option to achieve the same result:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a repos < <(
  find "$HOME/projects" -type d -execdir test -d {}/.git \; -print -prune)
```

Either way, once you have the pathnames in the `repos` array, you can then assign CDPATH like so:

```
CDPATH=${repos[0]}$(printf ":%s" "${repos[@]:1}"})
```